# Semantical ErrorThe annotation "@MappedSuperclass" in class App\Entity\User\ AdminUser was never imported

Tags: sylius, sylius-1.3

Hello i try to install RbacPlugin for the sylius i follow step per step but i have error. i have this error

[Semantical Error] The annotation "@MappedSuperclass" in class App\Entity\User\
  AdminUser was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for
   this annotation?

AdminUser.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity\User;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\AdminUser as BaseAdminUser;
use Sylius\RbacPlugin\Entity\AdministrationRoleAwareInterface;
use Sylius\RbacPlugin\Entity\AdministrationRoleAwareTrait;

/**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 * @Table(name="sylius_admin_user")
 */
class AdminUser extends BaseAdminUser implements AdministrationRoleAwareInterface
{
    use AdministrationRoleAwareTrait;
}
```

config/_sylius.yaml

```
sylius_user:
    resources:
        admin:
            user:
                classes:
                    model: App\Entity\AdminUser
```

routes/sylius_rbac.yaml

```
sylius_rbac:
    resource: "@SyliusRbacPlugin/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

config/packages/sylius_rbac.yaml

```
imports:
    - { resource: "@SyliusRbacPlugin/Resources/config/config.yml" }
```

its in step 6 when need migrate, what i can do for leave this?

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass;
```

> declare(strict_types=1);
>
> namespace App\Entity\User;
>
> use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity;
>
> use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
>
> use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\AdminUser as BaseAdminUser;
>
> use Sylius\RbacPlugin\Entity\AdministrationRoleAwareInterface;
>
> use Sylius\RbacPlugin\Entity\AdministrationRoleAwareTrait;
>
> use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappedSuperclass;